# Recursively remove elements from nested array if key exists in blacklisted array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, filtering

I want to be able to remove elements from the multidimensional array by `key`

Example of such an array can be:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [todo] => code review
            [schedule] => Array
                (
                    [endDate] => 2019-05-10T00:00:00+01:00
                    [startDate] => 2019-05-09T00:00:00+01:00
                )

            [codeDetails] => Array
                (
                    [language] => PHP
                    [type] => class
                    [abstract] => true
                    [methodCount] => Array
                        (
                            [public] => 3
                            [protected] =>
                            [private] => 1
                        )

                    [LOC] => 123
                    [cyclomaticComplexity] => 4
                    [author] => Array (
                            [name] => Lukasz
                            [email] => private@tulik.io
                        )
                )

        )
)
```

I have two methods, `recursiveArrayDelete` removes any elements where the callback returns `true`:

```php
private function recursiveArrayDelete(array &$array, callable $callback): array
{
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = $this->recursiveArrayDelete($value, $callback);
        }
        if ($callback($value, $key)) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Second, removes properties all included in `restrictedProperties` from the `array`:

```php
private function sanitizedArray(array &$array, array &$restrictedProperties): array
{
    foreach ($restrictedProperties as $restrictedProperty) {
        $this->recursiveArrayDelete(
            $array,
             static function () use ($array, $restrictedProperty): bool {
                array_walk_recursive(
                    $array,
                    static function ($value, $key) use (&$bool, $restrictedProperty) {
                         // here $bool is as expected from condition
                         $bool = $key === $restrictedProperty;
                     });
                  // here is always false
                 return $bool; 
             });
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Example of usage:

```php
$this->sanitizedResponse($data, ['methodCount', `endDate`]);
```

Should remove these elements from array. But as I mentioned in commenrt `sanitizedArray` where `return $bool;` always result in `false`.

Comment: It seems `$bool` will only ever compare the last key in the array with the restricted property?

Comment: @Nick You are right, do you have an idea how can I implement it correctly?

Comment: I think your callback is too complicated, it's attempting to recurse where you are already doing that in the recursiveArrayDelete function. It probably just needs to compare the key with values in the restrictedProperty array. Unfortunately I don't have time to look at it in more detail right now.

Comment: Why do you need the `$value` in the callback function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@dWinder's answer is almost perfect. But when I played around with it a bit more I noticed that it would *not* delete an array under a given "restricted property".

Let us assume that all `"D"`-elements were to be removed:

dWinder's solution would result in:

```
Array
(
    [A] => aa
    [B] => Array
        (
            [A] => aaa
            [B] => bb
        )

    [C] => cc
    [D] => Array
        (
            [E] => ee
        )

)
```

The array under `"D"` is still there. But when you switch the `if` condition and action with that of the `else if` you get the (assumed!) desired result:

```
Array
(
    [A] => aa
    [B] => Array
        (
            [A] => aaa
            [B] => bb
        )

    [C] => cc
)
```

So, the improved function code should look something like this (I am quoting parts of @dWinder's solution here):

```
$arr = array("A" => "aa", "B" => ["A" => "aaa", "B" => "bb"], "C" => "cc", "D" => ["E" =>"ee"]);

function array_filter_recursive(array &$array, callable $callback) {
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
        if ($callback($key, $value))   unset($array[$key]);
        else if (is_array($value))     array_filter_recursive($value, $callback);
    }
}

function sanitizedArray(&$arr, $restrictedProperties) {
    foreach($restrictedProperties as $prop) {
        array_filter_recursive($arr, function($k, $v) use ($prop) {return $prop == $k;});
    }
}
sanitizedArray($arr, ["D"]);
print_r($arr);
```

See here for a demo: https://3v4l.org/05tc7

Comment: Nice catch - you may take my answer and add it to yours so this question will have 1 full post for solution

Answer (score 2):

You done very well. Notice you have 2 issues: first you doing the recursion in both function and you reassign to `$bool` - so only the last compare is the one that count (this is why you getting false all the time).

I would make your code more simpler this way:

```
function array_filter_recursive(array &$array, callable $callback) {
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
        if ($callback($key, $value)) unset($array[$key]);
        else if (is_array($value)) array_filter_recursive($value, $callback);
    }
}

function sanitizedArray(&$arr, $restricted, $keys = false) {
    foreach($restricted as $val) {
        array_filter_recursive($arr, function($k, $v) use ($val, $keys) {return $keys ? ($val === $k) : ($val === $v);});
    }
}
```

Now you can simply use it as your example: `$this->sanitizedResponse($data, ['methodCount', 'endDate'], true);`

Here is live example with fake data: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/tqUm9)

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Tulikowski - there was a bug in my post - cars10m found it. Updated my answer

Comment: @dWinter @cars10m I think this nicer here `array_filter_recursive($arr, function($k, $v) use ($val, $keys) {return $keys ? ($val === $k) : ($val === $v);});` Could we edit/merge both solutions?

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Tulikowski update my answer (include the live example). I will leave car10m to update his